# How to position nested divs

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid blue;position:relative;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;float:left;">Some words here!!!</div>
  <div id="Pleasedontmovetoleftsideandstayput" style="display:inline-block;float:left;border:1px solid green;">
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;display:block;float:left;">Some words here!!!Some words here!!!Some words here!!! </div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;display:block;float:left;">Some words here!!!Some words here!!!Some words here!!! </div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;display:block;float:left;">Some words here!!!Some words here!!!Some words here!!! </div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;display:block;float:left;">Some words here!!!Some words here!!!Some words here!!! </div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;display:block;float:left;">Some words here!!!Some words here!!!Some words here!!! </div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;display:block;float:left;">Some words here!!!Some words here!!!Some words here!!! </div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;display:block;float:left;">Some words here!!!Some words here!!!Some words here!!! </div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px;display:block;float:left;">Some words here!!!Some words here!!!Some words here!!! </div>
    <div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want `#Pleasedontmovetoleftsideandstayput` to stay put and not move to the left side when I keep adding content into it. When i add content into it, and reach at the end of row , it expands and move to left to fill 100% of row, which I don't want.

Comment: Not sure i understand, you want that div to be to the right side of first one? If so, you need to define width to it and float it, or go with display table and table cells.

Comment: i see...and u say it is impossible do it without using table right?

Comment: corret, they will by default drop down if no width is specified.

Comment: just add a width rule in the CSS